# Why doesn't my TextBlock style inherit from my base style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a base Style

```
<Style x:Key="BaseFontControl" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
</Style>
```

and a TextBlock Style, where I can't use the Style above as base Style. It says `Target type TextBlock is not convertable to base type Control`. How can I work around this?

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../XAMLStyles/BaseFontControl.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<Style x:Key="TextStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FontControl}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="DroidSans"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBlock` is not derived from `Control`, hence a Style that targets `TextBlock` can't be based on one that targets `Control`.

You may change your base style to target `FrameworlElement`:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseFontControl" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="13"/>
</Style>
```

This approach takes advantage from the fact that the `TextBlock.FontSize` and `Control.TextBlock` properties use the same dependency property. So it also sets the `FontSize` property of elements that are derived from `Control`.